# How to Run Javascript code/script by itself like php bots?

Tags: javascript, bots

i am reading websocket data in javascript and doing further procedures like inserting data in mysql database.

but all this happens when i open .html page containing javascript code in it.

How can i run the javascript program/code all by itself from lets say command line ?

like the php codes/programmes/bot does , invoking from shell and it can keep doing what its been coded to do, without stopping.

so i can set it as a cron job and it will do its thing on time, instead of me opening .html file every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what [node.js](https://nodejs.org) is for. Instead of putting a `<script>` tag in an HTML file, you would just run your JS file ala `$ node myscript.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Installe nodejs and you can run .js files by

```
$ node myscript.js
```

if you want your script to run forever then you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever like this

```
$ forever start myscript.js
```